# How to stop a for loop earlier? [Python]

Tags: python, selenium

I have this for loop:

```
chat_color = chat.value_of_css_property('color')
color_check = 'rgb(86, 206, 39)'

for item in third_list:
    if chat_color == color_check:
       break
    text_input.send_keys(item)
    time.sleep(1)
    text_input.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

The loop types words from a word list in a textarea using selenium chrome webdriver.
I want the loop to stop if the color condition is met.
In my case, however, the for loop **doesn't** stop typing words.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to re-evaluate chat_color based on the input to the textarea you would need to check if the css value is updated in each iteration of the loop. Otherwise it just stores the initial value and from row 1 in your example and never updates. try moving row 1 into the first row of the loop instead and see if it works.

```py
color_check = 'rgb(86, 206, 39)'

for item in third_list:
    chat_color = chat.value_of_css_property('color')
    if chat_color == color_check:
       break
    text_input.send_keys(item)
    time.sleep(1)
    text_input.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```